# MPI CPU binding to specific core range

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, cpu, hpc

I am running a desktop with 32 cores (physical) on Windows 10 and have various MPI jobs I launch. I am trying to avoid a scheduler such as PBS as it is overkill for a single user, I am instead looking for if there is a way to specify which cores the MPI-task is launched on?

i.e. :

```
mpiexec -n 8 [core 0 to core  7] task.1
mpiexec -n 8 [core 8 to core 15] task.2      # etc...
```

I have seen various methods posted using `powershell` to set processor affinity but these do not appear to work, there are also options in the Intel MPI for :

```
  Processor topology options:
    -bind-to                         process binding
    -map-by                          process mapping
    -membind                         memory binding policy
```

But `-map-by` does not seem to lock to a specific core.

Comment: Which MPI library are you using? If you run more than one job per node, regardless the number of users, a job scheduler might not be an overkill.

Comment: Hi Gilles, thanks for the reply,

The MPI library is Intel(R) MPI Library, Version 2019  Build 20180829, which is bundled with the software I am running/launching. The issue with switching to a job scheduler is (I'm not sure if windows HPC on server can do this well?) PBS pro requires a few old visual studio depended features and it looked like quite a patchy solution.

Comment: not sure about Windows, but on Linux you can use the I_MPI_PIN_PROCESSOR_LIST environment variable, and it is up to you to set it to the right value (e.g. `0-7` or `8-15` or `16-23` or `24-31`

Comment: Hi Gilles, it was exactly that in windows: mpiexec -genv I_MPI_PIN_PROCESSOR_LIST=0,1,2,3. I also tried with windows HPC pack and you can eihter let mpiexec or the windows HPC scheduler assign the cores. With windows it allows a job que on the core, however, it also places it on core 0 which is used for the que system (stalls the computer).